# HTML String is not parsed with iText XML parser

Tags: java, xml, itext, xmlworker

I am unable to parse below HTML string using iText's xmlworker-5.5.9.jar

```
String FOOTER = "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\"><tr><td><span class=\"bold\">Footer</span></td><td align=\"right\">Some title</td></tr></table>";
```

by below helper class:

```
XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(FOOTER, CSS);
```

I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.pdfelement.NoNewLineParagraph.setMultipliedLeading(F)V
```

I saw iText's documentatin and [answer in this forum too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394158/how-to-add-html-headers-and-footers-to-a-page/33426258).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're using XML Worker 5.5.9, but which version of iText are you using? Also: are you sure you are using the same versions when executing the code as you are when compiling? This doesn't look like a real iText problem. It looks like an ordinary Java compiling vs executing problem.

Comment: I checked in the commits on github and I found that the field and so the method that you're looking for it is been moved in the class Phrase. Here the [commit](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/commit/10e415435474c0d78a997ca9a46ba9d8ad698aeb), I think that now you can found the method into this class itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/Phrase.java

Comment: Or you can downgrade the version, as @BrunoLowagie has suggested. It's sure  that the version  5.5.6 has the method that you are looking for.

Comment: Both the iText and xml worker version is same, i.e. 5.5.9

Comment: When I wrap **Footer** text inside **<span>** tag then I get above error.

Answer (score 0):

The above exception is beacause of uncompatibility of xmlWorker.jar and itextpdf.jar. So, to avoid above exception use single itextpdf.jar in your project and that is above itextpdf-5.5.1.jar version.