# I'm using itextpdf for pdf but here header&footer is overlapping with main content

Tags: android, itext

This is my header and footer section

```
           @Override
    public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    Log.d("Vijay","onStart 1");
    String phone = "Phone - 9850030179";
    String qualification = "MBBS";

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    Phrase dr_name = new Phrase("Raghani Doctor ("+qualification 
     +")",header_font);
    Phrase clinic_name = new Phrase("Ridhhi Clinic",setFontWeight(10));
    Phrase reg_no = new Phrase("Registration no. - 
    572017",setFontWeight(10));
    Phrase phone_no = new Phrase(phone,setFontWeight(10));
    //Phrase qualify = new Phrase(qualification,setFontWeight(10));
    Phrase address = new Phrase("Crescent Business Park, Riddhi Clinic, 
    SakiNaka, Mumbai, Pin - 400072",setFontWeight(10));
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,dr_name, 
    (document.right()+document.left())/2,document.top()-11,0);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,clinic_name, 
     (document.right()+document.left())/2,document.top()-21,0);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,reg_no, 
    (document.right()+document.left())/2,document.top()-30,0);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,address, 
    (document.right()+document.left())/2,document.top()-42,0);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,phone_no, 
    (document.right()+document.left())/2,document.top()-52,0);
    String separator = 
            "__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________";
     ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,new 
    Phrase(separator), 
      (document.right()+document.left())/2,document.top()-60,0);
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

    }

         @Override
       public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    Phrase medoc = new Phrase("Medoc", ffont);
    Phrase kspl = new Phrase("Kanishka Software", ffont);
    Phrase dash_left = new Phrase("- - - - - - - - - - - ", ffont);
    Phrase dash_right = new Phrase("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
     - - - -  ", ffont);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, medoc, 
    document.left(), document.bottom(), 0);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, kspl, 
      document.right(), document.bottom(), 0);




                    ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb,Element.ALIGN_LEFT,dash_left,document.left(),docume      nt.bottom()+10,0);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb,Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,dash_right,document.right(),document.bottom()+10,0);

        }
    }
```

Here in another activity i have created document. I also tried using another parameterised document constructor but still overlapping persists.

```
    document = new Document();
                    try {
                        PdfWriter pdfWriter =         PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(file));

                        HeaderFooter headerFooter = new HeaderFooter();

                        pdfWriter.setPageEvent(headerFooter);


                        Log.d("Vijay","Inside Pdf: "+arrayList);
                        document.open();
                        document.add(new Paragraph("\n \n \n \n Patient name - "+ patient_name));
                        document.add(new Paragraph("Patient DOB - "+pat_dob));
                        document.add(new Paragraph("Title: "+title.getText().toString()));
                        document.setMarginMirroring(false);
                       // ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfWriter.getDirectContent(),Element.ALIGN_CENTER,new Phrase(""+other_details),(document.right()+document.left())/2,document.top()-72,0);
                        //document.add(new Paragraph(title.getText().toString()));

                        Log.d("Vijay","Page no. "+pdfWriter.getPageNumber());

                        for(int m = 0;m<descriptionList.size();m++){
                            Log.d("Vijay","desc"+descriptionList.get(m).toString()+" "+m);
                            NewApplication newApplication = descriptionList.get(m);
                            if(newApplication.getFlag()==0){
                                document.add(new Paragraph("Content Description"));
                               // Paragraph content = new Paragraph(descriptionList.get(m).getAddDescription());
                               document.add(new Paragraph(descriptionList.get(m).getAddDescription()));
                                //content.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                               // document.add(content);
                                Log.d("Vijay","path : "+descriptionList.get(m).getAddDescription());
                            }
                            else{
                                Log.d("Vijay"," "+m);
                                Image image = Image.getInstance(arrayList_Path.get(m));
                                image.scaleAbsolute(200,250);
                                image.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
                                Paragraph para = new Paragraph(descriptionList.get(m).getType());
                                para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                                document.add(para);
                                document.add(image);

                            }
                        }
                        Log.d("Vijay","Array list "+ arrayList);


                        document.add(new Paragraph("Medicine Name - "+medicine_name));
                        document.add(new Paragraph("Medicine Time : "));
                        Log.d("Vijay","Page no.ssac "+pdfWriter.getPageNumber());
                        for (int l=0;l<timeArray.size();l++){
                            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(timeArray.get(l)+"\n");
                            document.add(paragraph);
                        }
                        Image image_sign = Image.getInstance(sign);
                        image_sign.scaleAbsolute(200,250);
                        image_sign.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                        Paragraph signing = new Paragraph("\n \n \n \n \n Signature");
                        signing.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                        document.add(signing);
                        Paragraph sign_dash = new Paragraph("_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ");
                        sign_dash.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                        document.add(sign_dash);
                        document.add(image_sign);

                        Log.d("Vijay","here pdf");
                        document.close();`[enter code here][1]`
```

Comment: Edit your question. Part of your code is not properly formatted.

Comment: As documented in many places (for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33426258/1622493)), **it is forbidden** to add content in the `OnStartPage()` method. There are better ways to draw a separator than using a `String` that consists of `_` characters. The same goes for your dashed line. You should read the official FAQ, for instance [Why does my header overlap with my content?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/page-events/itext7-why-does-my-header-overlap-my-content) The solution to your problem is in that answer.